# How can I change active form textinput with jquery, yii2?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I'm new to Yii and I'm struggling with this problem.
I have the active form field

```
      <?= $form->field($model, 'selected_values')->textInput() ?>
```

I have a table where are seats and I select them with js function

```
var selected_seats = 'an,example,variable'
```

and I want to pass this value to the 'selected_values' then submit the form.
I tried it with jquery but no success

```
$('#selected_values_id').val(selected_seats)
```

I would really appreciate if someone helped me!

Comment: Have you checked the ID of the generated field, the one you are trying to query by looks incorrect. Normally `ActiveForm` generates ids like: `mymodel-selected_seats`, unless you configured it manually; the `#selected_values_id` selector is probably not selecting anything.

Comment: It didn't work even when I added my own id to the textfiel, like: 
```
<?= $form->field($model, 'selected_values')->textInput(['id'=>'my_id']) ?>
```

Comment: Kindly try this `$('input[name=selected_values]').val('example')`